# Phonegap Facebook Login - Provided development URL rejected as Facebook Site URL

Tags: javascript, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to get https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/ to work for Phonegap, but the build tool provides as URL(http://10.0.0.6:3000/) that get rejected by Facebook.

Facebook message "This can't be a Facebook URL".